# Angular2 component loading external js lib file

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

I have a component that uses a javascript library. At the moment I am just using system.js to load the dependency

```
public ngOnInit() {
    System.import('lib').then(() => this.createControl());
}
```

However this delay in the initialization of the component is causing an issue with another, consuming component. Essentially the `createControl` function is running too late.

Is it possible to delay initialization of the entire component with angular until all dependencies are downloaded?

Comment: Why not load the dependency in the script tags before angular is loaded?  I do this with a few libraries, such as js.cookie and lodash.  They are already loaded by the time angular gets going.

Comment: I'm looking for a more modular approach :) I could load all dependencies initially yes, and although there are pro/cons on both sides, me personally I am leaning towards the modular/componentized approach.

Comment: Do you have routes in your app?

Comment: Yes I have routes. I know where you're going with this! But I was hoping to keep routing out of this since the component should be independent of the route. However can you also show me the route example (assuming you have one).

Comment: Try `@CanActivate(() => System.import('lib'))` annotation and initialize `this.createControl()` in constructor as normal.

Comment: So does it work, I didn't test?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to delay initialization of the entire component with angular until all dependencies are downloaded

Just add the `lib` as a dependency on the file. Put this on the top of the file that contains the component:

```
import * as lib from "lib"
```

This will effectively load "lib" *before* the application boots up.

Comment: This is not working. Getting a typescript compiler error that it cannot find the module "lib"

Comment: Fix : in `vendor.d.ts` add `declare module "lib" { var foo:any; export = foo; }`